# Excel: Multiple Selections in one drop down/one cell possible--perhaps using a listbox?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

The current problem I have has to do with tagging multiple categories to an a list of items in Excel. A rough example is shown below, with the second column being the CONCAT column that takes in data from many columns to the right (not shown, but they would be a data validation list for each subsystem and it's components).

Example Table Image:
[image: Example Table Image]

We have about 2000 rows to work through, so efficiency is key, and in evaluating the solution, we'll consider how long it takes to do this item by item.

Our current solution is to have a column for whole system (blank, or whole system), then a column for each subsystem and it's sub-subsystems. However, we run into issues as relevant items can be any from the list of sub-sub-systems, and then perhaps a whole subsystem (if that makes sense). We then have one column applying a CONCAT formula so that we list them all comma delimited in one cell.

I've added more detail on the kind of situation I am dealing with--the last row (cell B5 to be specific) is the desired outcome. The basic data validation/DDLB approach doesn't allow for multiple selections in a subsystem group, so I could either make one multi-select list box in VBA or one for each subsystem (probably faster to work with, as it becomes clear what the relevant subsystems are when working through this).

[Subsystem structure example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrMMX.png)

I considered creating an Access Database but that might be overkill--ultimately, we just need to be able to end up with one cell per row that has a list of the relevant sub systems.

Another thought is to have just one multi-select list box aka. https://www.contextures.com/excel-data-validation-listbox.html

Any suggestions? I am thinking that the VBA listbox is the way to go. I've done VBA programming here and there, so it should not be a big issue for me to get it working with some trial and error.

Comment: It would be useful to see a small sample of the un-shown column to the right, specifically for the sample output your screencap shows

Comment: Sorry for the delay--the material is sensitive so I need to figure out a way to Illustrate it otherwise. I am editing the post and adding it.